# HTML5 canvas - controlling what happens when drawing on same place

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, canvas, html5-canvas

How can i control what happens when i draw a line in the same coordinates as previous line?
Currently the color becomes brighter, but i want it to stay the same (or more accurately - i want the second line to on top of the first line).

I tried to do:

```
_context.setGlobalCompositeOperation(Composite.SOURCE_OVER);
```

But it seems to work only when drawing canvas on canvas, not when drawing on the same canvas.

Comment: Your problem isn't clear but may be related to either an alpha in the color you use or [fuzzy coordinates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373695/drawing-lines-in-canvas-but-the-last-ones-are-faded) leading to about the same effect.

Comment: I am always using ints when i draw. And alpha level is always FF

Comment: *"I am always using ints when i draw"* : that's your problem, you shouldn't. See my answer below.

Comment: See my comments to your answer

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your color has a full alpha, your problem is probably related to the fact you draw lines of width 1 at integer coordinates.

Look at the following fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/RAgak/

Drawing at integer coordinates makes the line wider and fuzzy. And drawing a second time makes it brighter. But this doesn't happen when I draw the line at half-integer coordinates.

```
var y = 10;
c.beginPath();
c.moveTo(0, y);
c.lineTo(30, y);
c.stroke(); // fuzzy
c.beginPath();
c.moveTo(50, y+0.5);
c.lineTo(80, y+0.5);
c.stroke(); // ok
```

This is due to the fact lines are drawn over all pixels they're over (on canvas positionning is in float). When you want to draw precise vertical or horizontal lines in javascript on a canvas, you'd better have them in half ints.

See illustration : The first horizontal line was drawn with a y position of 1. This line is fuzzy and wide. The second horizontal line was drawn with a y position of 4.5. It is thin and precise.

[image]

The solution, at least when drawing horizontal or vertical lines (or rects), is to take the width of the line into account and draw at integer or half-integer coordinates.

Comment: This is not the problem. I tried the half ints solution, but the result is the same. I also made sure that global alpha is 1.0

Comment: The problem is that if i draw a red line from x1, y1 to x2, y2 and than draw the same line again, the color becomes brighter.

Comment: See my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/RAgak/1/. With a line of width 1 this happens only when drawing at integer coordinates (for an horizontal or vertical line).

Comment: Can you build a fiddle demonstrating your problem if my answer doesn't appear to solve it ?

Comment: Try the following: http://jsfiddle.net/ptBz8/2/ try it with and without the last line and see the difference

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/uH4Jg/ : with +0.5 drawing twice at the same position doesn't make it brighter.

Comment: But what if the line is not vertical or horizonal?

Comment: Then it's not so easy. I have no simple general solution as the problem is inherent to the drawing model (bitmap model + antialiasing).