# Avoiding color blending in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am drawing two rectangles in html5 canvas element. One of the edges on rectangle **a** is on the edge of rectangle **b**.

Rectangle **a** is green and rectangle **b** is blue.

The result is that the common edge is neither blue nor green : Its color is some blend of the two.

I tried setting globalCompositeOperation to source over, but it did not help.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That's because lines are drawed over more than one screen pixel.

The drawing model is based on float coordinates, rounded values being **between** the screen pixels.

To avoid that blending, always draw lines whose line width is one pixel at coordinates `Math.round(x)+0.5`.

Here's [a related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373695/drawing-lines-in-canvas-but-the-last-ones-are-faded) with a picture.

And here's some code I made to help drawing thin lines and rectangles :

```
function drawThinHorizontalLine(c, x1, x2, y) {
    c.lineWidth = 1;
    var adaptedY = Math.floor(y)+0.5;
    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo(x1, adaptedY);
    c.lineTo(x2, adaptedY);
    c.stroke();
}

function drawThinVerticalLine(c, x, y1, y2) {
    c.lineWidth = 1;
    var adaptedX = Math.floor(x)+0.5;
    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo(adaptedX, y1);
    c.lineTo(adaptedX, y2);
    c.stroke();
}

function Rect(x,y,w,h){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
}

Rect.prototype.drawThin = function(context) {
    drawThinHorizontalLine(context, this.x, this.x+this.w, this.y);
    drawThinHorizontalLine(context, this.x, this.x+this.w, this.y+this.h);
    drawThinVerticalLine(context, this.x, this.y, this.y+this.h);
    drawThinVerticalLine(context, this.x+this.w, this.y, this.y+this.h);
}
```

Example :

```
context.strokeColor = 'red';
var r = new Rect(20, 23, 433, 14);
r.drawThin(context);
```

Comment: What if the rectangles are rotated?

Comment: Then, just like the lines, there will be lightly blended with the background but the effect is usually much harder to notice than with horizontal or vertical lines.