# Redrawing the same canvas lines is not accurate

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have a simple canvas element :

```
<canvas id="floor" style="background-color:#f7f7f7;border:1px #000 solid;"    >
</canvas>
```

I also have a `draw` function which creates vertical/horizontal lines :

```
function draw(){

  ctx.translate(0.25, 0.25);
  for (var x = size; x < canvas.width; x += size)  { //vertical
      ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
      ctx.lineTo(x, canvas.height);
  }

  for (var y = size; y < canvas.height; y += size) { //horizontal
     ctx.moveTo(0, y);
     ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, y);
  }

  ctx.strokeStyle = "#C1C1C1";
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

The button calls this `draw` function again :

```
$(".b").on('click',function (){
  draw();
})
```

But if I click this button many times, it seems that it adds more lines making it look thicker :

[image]

**Question**

Why doesn't the canvas look the same if I draw exactly the same lines?

And how can I fix my code to make it look the same?

[**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/xabagehebe/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Looks like you need to clear the canvas.

Comment: What is your `ctx` that you translate on every re-draw? `ctx.translate(0.25, 0.25);`

Comment: Every time you call `draw()` it does a `ctx.translate(0.25, 0.25)`.

Comment: @Adam tried to clear - still problem remains : http://jsbin.com/vibecanize/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @Justinas if you dont do this , your lines look different

Comment: Start from 0.5, not from 0, otherwise the lines are anti-aliased.

Comment: @Teemu  I didnt start from 0. I started from 0.25 . That's what i told justinas

Comment: @AndrewMorton [much better](http://jsbin.com/dayemeqore/1/edit?html,js,output) , it doesn't grow further , but it does grow a bit. - is there any option not to ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Instead of 0.75, use 0.5 everywhere ...

Comment: `tileSize = 15.75` ... Set `tileSize = 15.5` and `ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5);`, then there wont be blurred lines.

Comment: Ah, this must be a dup ... Anyway, 1px wide line is drawn in between two pixels on the screen, if the coordinates won't match, the line will be anti-aliased.

Comment: A good explanation of what happens: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10379995/1169519

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the canvas before redrawing the lines and use the context begin path method:

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('floor');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var size = 20

function draw(){
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
  //ctx.translate(0.25, 0.25);
  
  //this is important!
  ctx.beginPath();
  
  for (var x = size; x < canvas.width; x += size)  { //vertical
      ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
      ctx.lineTo(x, canvas.height);
  }

  for (var y = size; y < canvas.height; y += size) { //horizontal
     ctx.moveTo(0, y);
     ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, y);
  }

  ctx.strokeStyle = "#C1C1C1";
  ctx.stroke();
   
}

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', draw);
```

```html
<canvas id="floor" style="background-color:#f7f7f7;border:1px #000 solid;"    >
</canvas>

<button id="button">
redraw
</button>
```

Comment: Works. thanks. indeed it was the beginPath. The anti-aliased part was already fine

Answer (score 2):

On every call of `draw` you need to start a new path with:

`ctx.beginPath();`